Pycharm doesn't support show function in .str?

firstly, I'm really sorry for my bad English.
Im trying to use .str.split(), but it doesn't show.
Nevertheless, when I complete that code, it works well.
Im using Pycharm 2024.1 and anaconda 3.
I don't think this problem is hardware related.
(Im using Mac OS Somoma 14.1. with m3 pro.)
Doesn't Pycharm support code completion with .str?
I turned off ai supported tool which is included in Pycharm.
But, nothing happened.
(I thought that there's a collision with AI supported tool, but doses't work.)
Also I reinstall Pycharm but it also doesn't work.
Also modifying Code Completion doesn't work.

So it works fine but you're having issues with the autocompletion on your editor?

@DanielCruz yes, right. But it makes me uncomforted. Unlike Pycharm, VS code support auto complete same situation.

I understand. I don't know much about Pycharm. I use Vscode. I recommend you to make sure you have the latest version. Also I was checking on the examples and it seems that .astype() converts the current object, maybe there is no need to reassing the variable. Just call .astype()  as described here, maybe the way you're calling it works, but maybe this other way can be better understood by the IDE. I dont have pycharm to try but take a look https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

@DanielCruz thanks a lot. .astype() was used only for letting Pycharm know that is string and deleting .astype doesn't works...

If you are trying to split a string then its just .split() - you don't use  .str.split().
astr = "this should be split by spaces"
x = astr.split()
print(x)




thank you for your help. but in this case, I wanna split pandas series object, so I need .str.... Same as your picture, it works with string. I'm really sorry for that I didn't give you all of solution that I tried.

@cauai you should add the pandas tag and add this to your question(edit it so that it specifies in pandas)

really thanks for your help,,haha I just choose to be adapted. thanks for your help
